# IE7 float clearing for definition list

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I have a definition list that I want to display with label/definition pairs next to each other.

The following code works correctly in all modern browsers.  I'm trying to get it working in IE7 but the dd values are not respecting the previously cleared dt's.  What else do I need to do to get them to stack like they do in chrome or ff.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .label-value-list {
    }
   .label-value-list dt {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      width: 100px;
   }
   .label-value-list dd {                           
      float: left;
   }
</style>

<dl class="label-value-list">
   <dt>First Label</dt>
   <dd>This is the first value</dd>

   <dt>Second Label</dt>
   <dd>I should be below the first value<br/>and I have two lines</dd>

   <dt>Third Label</dt>
   <dd>I should be below the second value</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
*:first-child+html .label-value-list dd {
   float: none;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

to your CSS.

See http://jsfiddle.net/FFMvY/1/

Comment: Thanks, came to the same conclusion as I saw your post.  Odd that it doesn't require the zoom hack to work correctly.

Comment: @bmancini I think `display:inline-block` and `zoom:1` have the same effect here, that of setting the hasLayout flag.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `float` from `DD` or use own self-cleared `DL` for each `DT`/`DD` pair. BTW, in second case it probably makes sense to use `display: table` instead of `float`.

Comment: Removing float from DD causes indentation issues with multi-line DD content.  Any fix for that?

Comment: Yuo can add `margin-left: 100px` to your `DD`. Though I would prefer `display: table` as a more flexible solution.